# C# Accessing a dictionary from another class is not working

Tags: c#, object, dictionary, reference

I'm fairly new to C# and have been trying to learn for the last 3 days. I am curious as to why the below code is not working properly? I get the following error: **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** when I try to call data.dOffsets["roomtargets"]. However, calling data.sProcessName does work without any error..

I have two classes/files. The program.cs:

```
class Program
    {
        public static Data data = new Data();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("data.sProcessName: {0}", data.sProcessName);
            Console.WriteLine("data.dOffsets[\"roomtargets\"]: {0}", data.dOffsets["roomtargets"]);
```

And the Data.cs:

```
public class Data
    {
        public string sProcessName { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, int> dOffsets { get; set; }

        public Data()
        {
            sProcessName = "Client";

            Dictionary<string, int> dOffsets = new Dictionary<string, int>()
            {
                {"roomtargets", 0x0018FA48}
            };
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
        Dictionary<string, int> dOffsets = new Dictionary<string, int>()
        {
            {"roomtargets", 0x0018FA48}
        };
```

This code initialize a dictionary as an inner variable within the constructor. Change it to:

```
        dOffsets = new Dictionary<string, int>()
        {
            {"roomtargets", 0x0018FA48}
        };
```

or `this.dOffsets` to make it more clear.

Comment: Ofcourse! Basically I was redeclaring the same variable in the constructor but no longer as a public? Thank you for the quick and helpful reply!

Comment: You variable was declared within the constructor scope, so it was valid only within that constructor. Because the name of the variable was the same as one on class members it shadowed that member (a property in your case). After that accessing that property have to be done using `this` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Your dOffsets  is local to the constructor. Your class already has that property, so you don't need declare another local variable there

```
public Data()
{
    sProcessName = "Client";

    dOffsets = new Dictionary<string, int>()
    {
        {"roomtargets", 0x0018FA48}
    };
}
```

this should work