# Creating and Adding to a Dictionary in One Class, Accessing the Dictionary in Main Program

Tags: c#, class, dictionary

In my C# code, I'm needing to create a Dictionary and Add entries to it in a particular class. Then, in my main program, I'm needing to check and see if my ID numbers I'm working with are in that Dictionary. I was imagining something simply like

```
public class Pref
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> PreferredPartners =  new Dictionary<string,string>();
    PreferredPartners.Add("ID1part1" , "ID1part2");
    PreferredPartners.Add("ID2part1" , "ID2part2");
    . 
    .
    .
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
          .
          .
          .
          if(Pref.PreferedPartners.ContainsKey("someIDpart1"))
          {
                do something;
          else
          {
                do something else;
          }
          .
          .
          .
    }
}
```

I've tried the above code but it doesn't like my "PreferredPartners.Add("","")" statement in the Pref class; saying that it's a field that's used like a type and that the () are invalid tokens. I thought doing it a separate class would still be identical to a "normal" ititialization in the main code. I tried looking at [C# Accessing a dictionary from another class is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304770/c-sharp-accessing-a-dictionary-from-another-class-is-not-working) for help but couldn't quite piece it together for my situation.

How can I create this dictionary (and add to it) appropriately in my Pref class and how should my main program code read in order to let me check to see if certain ID's are in the Dictionary?

Comment: You need an instance of the `Pref` class in order to access the dictionary from the entry-point. See [Objects (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173110.aspx).

Comment: put your `prefferedpartners` var in the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to initialize your dictionary without having to do it in a method you should use

```
public class Pref
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> PreferredPartners =  new Dictionary<string,string>()
    {
        {"ID1part1" , "ID1part2"},
        {"ID2part1" , "ID2part2"}
    };
}
```

It is called Collection Initializer and you could find [documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx)

Of course, if you want to access a non-static member of a class, you need an instance of that class

```
void Main()
{
    Pref p = new Pref();
    if(p.PreferedPartners.ContainsKey("someIDpart1"))
    {
       Console.WriteLine(p.PreferredPartners["ID1part1"]);
       ....
    }
    else
    {
       ....;
    }
}
```

Now, you could ask yourself if this dictionary contains the same data for all instances of your class Pref. In that case it make more sense to have this dictionary declared as a static variable so it is created just one time at the first reference of the class and not in every instance of the class

```
public class Pref
{
    public static Dictionary<string, string> PreferredPartners =  new Dictionary<string,string>()
    {
        {"ID1part1" , "ID1part2"},
        {"ID2part1" , "ID2part2"}
    };
}

void Main()
{
    if(Pref.PreferedPartners.ContainsKey("someIDpart1"))
    {
       Console.WriteLine(Pref.PreferredPartners["ID1part1"]);
       ....
    }
    else
    {
       ....;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this is reasonable. You should wrap the code of adding elements in your dictionary in the constructor of your class

```
public class Pref()
{
    PreferredPartners.Add("ID1part1" , "ID1part2");
    PreferredPartners.Add("ID2part1" , "ID2part2");
}
```

You can't add items to a dictionary the way you did. At first you have to create a dicionary like you have already done:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> PreferredPartners =  new Dictionary<string,string>();
```

Then inside a method of your class, you should fill this dictionary or you could fill it in another class that you create an instance of your `Pref` class.

Then in the `Main`, you have to create an instance of your class, like below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Pref pref = new Pref();

    if(pref.PreferedPartners.ContainsKey("someIDpart1"))
    {

    } 
}
```

**However**, I think a better approach would be to create this dictionary inside your `Main` method, since I don't think you need a class for your purpose. Something like that:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Here we create our dictionary using a collection initializer,
    // for further documentation about this, please have at the link at the bottom.
    Dictionary<string, string> preferredPartners = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"ID1part1" , "ID1part2"},
        {"ID2part1" , "ID2part2"}  
    }

    if(preferredPartners.ContainsKey("someIDpart1"))
    {

    } 
}
```

[How to: Initialize a Dictionary with a Collection Initializer (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx).

Comment: If OP wants to access it, it'll need to have an instance created, or be a static class.

Comment: This is correct. I will refer to it immediately. Thank you !

Comment: Note that you could optionally use a [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues here.

1) Your Pref class has to be static if you're going to use it like you are from your main class. The other option would be to create an instance of the class and then use the instance in your main program.

2)  You will need to add items from a constructor or some other method within the Pref class.  You could also use the collection initializer as mentioned in other posts.

```
public static class Pref{
    public static Dictionary<string, string> PreferredPartners =  new Dictionary<string,string>();

    static Pref(){
        PreferredPartners.Add("ID1part1" , "ID1part2");
        PreferredPartners.Add("ID2part1" , "ID2part2");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
          .
          .
          .
          if(Pref.PreferedPartners.ContainsKey("someIDpart1"))
          {
                do something;
          else
          {
                do something else;
          }
          .
          .
          .
    }
}
```

OR

```
public class Pref{
    public Dictionary<string, string> PreferredPartners =  new Dictionary<string,string>();

    public Pref(){
        PreferredPartners.Add("ID1part1" , "ID1part2");
        PreferredPartners.Add("ID2part1" , "ID2part2");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
          .
          .
          var p = new Pref();  //Instantiate your pref class.
          .
          if(p.PreferedPartners.ContainsKey("someIDpart1"))
          {
                do something;
          else
          {
                do something else;
          }
          .
          .
          .
    }
}
```

Comment: If you make the class static, you'll have to make `PreferredPartners` static also.